# Reminders in Google Calendar

Tags: calendar

I'm confused about synchronization of events between Google Calendar and Android (version 2.2). I used to receive a SMS and/or email reminder about events on Google Calendar (I set them up on PC). However, as I see, I can add ony a pop-up reminders using Android. Moreover official Google calendar application doesn't display SMS and email remainders conected with particular events...
One more thing, I had set up default reminders for specific calendars in Google Calendar. When I add new event on Android and synchronize then, it shows up, that Android override my default calendars' reminders!

Is it a common bug or something? Or maybe it's a Google policy, that I don't understand...

Answer (score 3):

These aren't bugs or policies, Google simply hasn't implemented all of the Google Calendar web features in the Android Calendar app.  You can browse Android Calendar feature requests and bugs, as well as request and report them, here: http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar/issues/list